# "Whats new" date restriction on API

Tags: api, activecollab

I am developing an app with the Active Collab API using the [What's New](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/utilities/whats-new.html) endpoint.

I am retrieving this regularly, so I have the latest information. I was wondering if there was a way to specify the activity by date to get the items since then?

For example, instead of getting 50 records and processing the 50 every time, if I could pass a `from` parameter (with a timestamp) to only collate activity since that time then that would help with both my processing and the size of the request (and knowing how many things have happened since)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What's New API end point only has a daily filter:

`/whats-new/daily/YYYY-MM-DD`

Both global and daily What's new API end-points are paginated, so you can loop through responses by providing (and incrementing) `page` GET argument:

`/whats-new?page=2`

until you reach records that are older than the timestamp that you are looking for (or get an empty result). At that point, you just break and you have all the updates that were looking for.

Comment: Thanks fore the reply - the daily filter might help with what I'm after 

Comment: Happy to help! 

Comment: @llija is it intentional that updates to time records are not in the "whats new" (e.g. changing task type, billable status etc.)?

Comment: What's new API is there to power Activity page. If particular changes are not communicated on the Activity page, than you'll not find them in the API. That's the primary logic behind the solution. Any particular question should be viewed from that lense.